# Angular wait for outpout of component in a service

Tags: angular, service, output

in my component Angular I receive an output in my method "onChargementBandeau($event)" like this :

```
    <map-layout  (chargementBandeau)="onChargementBandeau($event)" [mlParamEntree]="mlParamEntreeMapLayout" >
</map-layout>
```

And when I reveive that data, I call my service "dataTagService" to pass the data to a variable contained in this service :

```
  onChargementBandeau(individu: Individu) {
this.dataTagService.statutDemandeurEmploi = individu.libelleMotifDePresence; }
```

My issue is that I need the value of the variable "statutDemandeurEmploi" before I call the method "tag" :

```
   @Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class DataTagService {
  private static VALUE_NOM_APPLICATION = 'pn169';
  idDgasi: string;
  idRci : string;
  codeAurore: string;
  statutDemandeurEmploi : string;
  dataTag: { [id: string]: DataTag } = {};

  constructor(
    private tagService: TmsService,
    private utilisateurService: UtilisateurService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private logger: NGXLogger,
    private layoutComponent : LayoutComponent,
  ) {

    this.initUser();
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe((params: Params) => {
      this.idRci = params['cxalap'];
    });
  }
  
  initUser(): void {
    const utilisateur = this.utilisateurService.getUtilisateurEnSession();
    this.idDgasi = utilisateur.idDgasi;
    this.codeAurore = utilisateur.codeAurore;
  }

  tag(tagModel: RessourcesTagModel): void {
    const tag: DataTag = new DataTag();

    tag.name = tagModel.name;
    tag.type = tagModel.type;
    tag.level2 = 9;
    tag.chapters = tagModel.chapters;

    tag.identifiedVisitor = {
      id: this.idDgasi,
      category: 1,
    };

    tag.customVars = {
      provenance: '1',
      idDossier: this.idRci,
      pn: DataTagService.VALUE_NOM_APPLICATION,
      statutDemandeurEmploi: this.statutDemandeurEmploi,
      agence : this.codeAurore,
    };

    this.logger.info(tag);

    this.tagService.tag(tag);
  }
}
```

I don't know how to wait for the response of my output component for calling my tag method, because In my case the reverse happens, first the method is called and after the variable " statutDemandeurEmploi" takes the value of the component.

If you could give me some help to deal with this issue, I will be greatful.

Thank you

Comment: The only solution I find is : make both methods call a third one, which will verify the existence of both variables before calling `tag`.

Comment: Okay I see, but where I have to place this third method ? In my component or my service ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have an elegant solution, you must do set functions for each variable, and have them call one that verifies that the two variables have valid values.

tips:
You have to check because you need two values ​​but you only emit one, you could try to make the output send both in the form of a class, even with a default value

Use Setters to call service.